# How Can I Record a Javascript Driven window.open in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

**Here's the problem:**

I used jQuery to allow a user to click on an element, and a jQuery click function runs a window.open command to open a new tab. This allows a user to click anywhere on the object, not just the a link, and go to the desired location. The link is a PDF. I can track clicks on the a tag element in Google Tag Manager, but I can't track clicks that open the window via javascript. I am using a trigger with regex looking for the .pdf suffix in Tag Manager.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class='floorplan'>
    <img target='_blank' src='images/floorplan-05.png' width='100%' alt='Floorplan 05'>
    <h4>05 Residence</h4>
    <span class='line'></span>
    <p>3 Bedroom / 3.5 Bath</p>
    <p>Living Area: 2,458 sq. ft.</p>
    <p><a href='pdf/floorplan-05.pdf' target='_blank'>Download PDF</a></p>
  </div>
```

And here's the javascript/jQuery:

```
$('.floorplan').click(function()
{
    var linky = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    window.open(linky,'_blank');
});
```

I'm not great at manipulating the dataLayer Google provides. How should I alter my javascript to fire the event trigger for my link? Here is some info about how things are set up in Tag Manager:

**The Tag**

- Name: PDF Clicks
- Category: PDF Click
- Action: {{Event}}
- Label: PDF | {{Click URL}}
- Value: 1

**The Trigger**

- Name: PDF Clicks
- Event: Click
- Trigger Type: Click
- Fire On: Click URL matches RegEx .pdf$

Comment: Hi, can you share how did you solve the problem?
 I'm facing the same issue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
$('.floorplan').click(function()
{
var linky = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
window.open(linky,'_blank');
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({'event':'link-click'});
});
```

to push value to dataLayer and then in GTM use Event with name link-click as a trigger to fire your tag.

Comment: Hey @mrbubu, thanks for the help! This is great for logging that an event happened, but it doesn't quite get me across the finish line. In the Tag, I'm saving the category as "PDF Click" and the Label as PDF | {{Click URL}}. How would I go about pushing those values in addition to the event? Would it be as simple as:

    dataLayer.push({'event':'link-click,'category':'PDF Click','label':'PDF | ' + linky});

Comment: If you do like this, you'll have to add 2 new variables in GTM  with Data Layer variable type to get values of category and label keys. Than you should use this variables as category and label in your GA tag. But be careful to separate keys and their values in your code with ":" and not with ',' as you did in your comment for 'label' key.

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick and dirty solution. Use jQuery to click on the object for you.

```
$('.floorplan').click(function(){
    $(this).find('a').attr('href').click();
});
```

This way you will be able to track the link through your current method.